# getting error after I am converting the result of ExecuteQuery() output to list

Tags: c#, sql, linq, executequery

I am using linq to sql for my project. But getting error after I am converting the result of `ExecuteQuery()` using the `.ToList()` extension:

```
var logentries = DB.ExecuteQuery<keyValueList>(string.Format(query));
keyValueList kv1 = logentries.ToList();// -->Error in this line as:
```

Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'DataLib.keyValueList'

Comment: Your type keyValueList is not a List<..> but a single entry of the returned list.

Comment: I would also used var kv1 = logentries.ToList(); then things will become clear to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ToList` returns a `List<T>` where `T` is `keyValueList`. But i think you want a single object, then either use `First`/`FirstOrdefault` or `Singler`/ `SingleOrDefault`:

```
keyValueList kv1 = logentries.FirstOrDefault();
```

The diference is, the `...OrDefault` methods return `null` if the input sequnce is empty whereas the `First/Single` throw an exeption. Furthermore `Single` throws an exception if there is more than one item(useful if that is impossible and should throw, for example because you are filtering by a unique property).

Comment: And you may want to check if List.Count() > 0 before you use First() or FirstOrDefault().  I've been burned too many times w/ FirstOrDefault().

Comment: @WEFX: Never use `Count()` if you want to know if there is one, use `Any`. Otherwise you will execute the whole query and count each item just to know that there's at least one. If you use `FirstOrDefault` you don't need to use `Any`. Just check `if(kv1 != null) ....`.

Comment: Actually i want to return a list<KeyValuePair> from the select query. As i am using Datacontext Just want to know also what ExecuteQuery() is going to return. I thought i'll use logentries in foreach to get the desired list and will return it.

Comment: @sameerpradhan: Then you want a `List<keyValueList> kv1 = logentries.ToList();`.